# spring integration wire-tap and logging-channel-adapter logging issue

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to add wire-tap to intercept the channel but it is not using my logback configuration but instead it uses org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger. 
  How do tell LoggingHandler.messageLogger to use lmy logback configuration?

```
<int:channel id="testChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="loggerChannel"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="loggerChannel" level="DEBUG"/>
```

My logback has following configurayion defined

```
<logger name="org.springframework" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.integration" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler" level="DEBUG"/>


<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLING"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For historical reasons, Spring uses commons-logging internally; you can wire in logback using slf4j.

See the [note in the Spring Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-logging).

Here's [another howto](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-log-in-spring-with-slf4j-and-logback/).

Essentially you need to exclude `commons-logging` from spring deps and add `jcl-over-slf4j`.